# Why Can't Fetch The Same Data Twice? NSFetchedResultsController Is Empty

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode4.3, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to fetch my data, but the results are empty! 
First, I have a table, with data from one NSFetchedResultsController. Until here, my code is right, and also I know I have the data. 
But then, I filter that NSFetchedResultsController, so I need another NSFetchedResultsController with the records without filter, I mean, all my records. So, I'm trying to fetch the data again, with another NSFetchedResultsController, using the same code, but the results is always empty!!!.

 This is the functions that I'm using:

```
+(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsControllerForEntity:(NSString*)entityName titleKey:(NSString*)titleKey sectionNameKeyPath:(NSString*)sectionNameKeyPath{

      NSFetchRequest *request=[self fetchRequestForEntity:entityName titleKey:titleKey sectionNameKeyPath:sectionNameKeyPath];    

      return [[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request 
                                            managedObjectContext:[self managedContext] 
                                            sectionNameKeyPath:sectionNameKeyPath 
                                            cacheName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@.%@",entityName,sectionNameKeyPath,titleKey]]autorelease];
 }



+(NSFetchRequest *) fetchRequestForEntity:(NSString*)entityName titleKey:(NSString*)titleKey sectionNameKeyPath:(NSString*)sectionNameKeyPath{

    NSFetchRequest *request=[[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init]autorelease];
    request.entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:[self managedContext]];
    NSSortDescriptor* titleSortDescriptor=titleKey?[[NSSortDescriptor alloc ]initWithKey:titleKey ascending:YES]:nil;
    NSSortDescriptor* sectionSortDescriptor=sectionNameKeyPath?[[NSSortDescriptor alloc ]initWithKey:sectionNameKeyPath ascending:YES]:nil;
    NSMutableArray * sortDescriptors=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if(sectionNameKeyPath){
        [sortDescriptors addObject:sectionSortDescriptor];
        [sectionSortDescriptor release];
    }
    if(titleKey){
        [sortDescriptors addObject:titleSortDescriptor];
        [titleSortDescriptor release];
    }

    request.sortDescriptors=sortDescriptors;
    [sortDescriptors release];

    request.fetchBatchSize=20;
    return request;
}
```

I don't understand, why If I'm using the same code, my NSFetchResultsController is empty!!!
I tried to fetch data from another entity, but the result is also empty...
Why I'm missing?
Thanks

Comment: The `+` in front of your method names looks problematic. Why did you create class methods?

Comment: Because I'm calling the function in another class. I've change + to -, but the result is the same...

Comment: That completely does not make sense. Class methods are sent to the class(`[MyClass method];`), instance methods are sent to an instance (`[myObject method];`). It should not even compile. I conclude that you are not calling the methods you think you are calling.

Comment: It compile!! And I already found my solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved my problem. Just re-declare the SET method for the NSFetchedResultsController object:

```
-(void)setFetchedItems:(NSFetchedResultsController *)newFetchedItems{
    [fetchedItems release];
    fetchedItems=[newFetchedItems retain];
    [fetchedItems performFetch:NULL];
}
```

I guess that's why my object always was empty. Because the object

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the same `NSFetchedResultsController`. Just change its `fetchRequest` property to reflect the data you like to fetch. E.g., to fetch all instances of a given entity, use

```
self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = nil;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

If you `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` is set up right, your table view should just update itself.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I can't use the same NSFetchResultsController, because one is for the table (for display), and I need another with all the data, the original data, for another purposes

Comment: Then simply create a second ivar `otherFetchedResultsController` and just copy-paste the accessor code of the original one, changing only the predicate and maybe sorting.